# Way to develop Web/Desktop App development (as compare to VS)

Tags: java

I know that it is a very basic question but I'm confuse please clarify. I have developed Windows and Web application on Visual Studio using C#.

VS provide Console Application for console app development

GUI based: Windows application/WPF  for software development

Web: ASP.net/MVC for Web development

and provide back end data base solution more appropriately SQL Server or access.

Now, in Java I have learnt java programming and worked Console Application using IntelliJ Idea.

My simple questions are:

- How can I develop desktop GUI based application in Java.??
- Which IDE I need to use?
- How can I develop web application on Java.  What are the compatible
  databases?
- Which is the Official IDE of Java where I can find all options like
  VS provides for Desktop or web app development?

Comment: You could start with [java swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/examples/start/index.html)

Comment: There is no official Java IDE, and there is no list of options, because the Java ecosystem is not primarily controlled by one company (although the specification is, and the most popular runtime implementation)

Comment: @immibis much helpful thing you said

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Answering 3 of your 4 questions:**

> How can I develop desktop GUI based application in Java.??

You should just simply download latest Java Developement Kit from official Oracle Site and install it. Don't forget to set `JAVA_HOME` and `JAVA_PATH` system variables.

> Which IDE I need to use?

Consider using EclipseIDE - IMO best free JavaIDE outhere.

> Which is the Official IDE of Java where I can find all options like VS provides for Desktop or web app development?

Dunno what options VS provides but there are many options in EclipseIDE - you'll like that stuff.

Comment: IntelliJ is more comfortable to me, nevertheless, good answer.

Comment: Isn't IntelliJ pay to use IDE?

Comment: There is a community version , but just buy it .. its worth every bit of it

Comment: sadly, questions perspective completely ignored

Comment: @Mohammad Faizan khan In which point?

Comment: Yes, but why does this matter?